# How can I make all of the IDisposable classes colored differently in the Visual Studio IDE?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ide

Title covers it all.  I'd like classes which implement IDisposable to show up in a specific color so I can know if I should wrap them in a using block.  Is there a setting or a process by which you can extend the IDE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is certainly possible to do this though it isn't as simple as just changing a setting. You would need to write a Visual Studio addin to accomplish this.

Visit http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsx/bb980955.aspx to get started. As others will point out. This is not for the faint of heart.

Here's a link that may point you toward what you are looking for:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166778.aspx

Comment: good points. here is another good link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.textmanager.interop.ivshicoloritem.aspx

Comment: I used to program ATL COM objects.  I'm not faint-hearted.

Answer (score 20):

I assume this will become easier/extension-free once Roslyn comes out, but this is presently not easy because you can't access the code as C# from an extension easily.

**In Resharper** it's easy, though! My example was tested in ReSharper 9.0. Sadly, there's no easy way to give this to you.

- Extensions -> Resharper -> Options -> Code Inspection -> Custom Patterns -> Add, dialog popup
- Select C# (upper left)
- Select "Find" (upper right)
- Add the pattern of `new $disp$($args$)`
- Pattern severity: Show as suggestion
- Description: Disposable construction
- "Add Placeholder" of type: `Type`, name: `disp`, type: `System.IDisposable`
- "Add Placeholder" of type: `Arguments`, name: `args`

Save and you'll now get a "suggestion" whenever a new disposable is being constructed.

Adding the pattern `$disp$ $var$ = $exp$;` could also be helpful.

- "Add Placeholder" of type: `Type`, name: `disp`, type: `System.IDisposable`
- "Add Placeholder" of type: `Expression`, name: `exp`
- "Add Placeholder" of type: `Identifier`, name: `var`

[image]

Comment: Good workaround, but not as good as using a special color for variables/expressions of type IDisposable since it sort of makes it look like all cases of creating disposables are errors. R# feature request submitted: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-472248

Comment: can you please mention how to setup "Add Placeholder" parts in case of your last mentioned pattern (`$disp$ $var$ = $exp$;`) so we could just see all declarations of disposable items in .cs file.

Comment: Thank. just i doubt that in that addition, you described `$args$` while missed to mention about `$var$` ? sorry for bothering, just I'm new there.

Comment: @T.Todua I did miss that. Thanks! Fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot.  This would require language service support and neither C# or VB.Net provide this functionality.

Cannot is probably too strong of a word.  It's certainly possible to do this with an Add-In which does deep inspection of the code and figures out hierarchies.  However it's a very non-trivial task.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, if FXCop or StyleCop can do this already. But then, it will be a post-compile suggestion/warning.

Resharper suggests this, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, there is a large set of tools to build VS extensions, [see Visual Studio 2008 SDK 1.1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=59EC6EC3-4273-48A3-BA25-DC925A45584D&displaylang=en)
But time required to build such an add-in will require more time that you will spend by browsing components and determining whether they are Disposable or not

Answer (score 0):

The word on the street is this kind of thing will [be much easier in VS.NET 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12199yxc%28VS.100%29.aspx).  The editor is being rewritten in WPF.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm a bad person for doing this, but I've been using this piece of code recently:

```
public static void BulkDispose(object[] objects)
{
  foreach (object o in objects)
  {
    if (o != null)
    {
      if (o is IDisposable)
      {
        IDisposable disposable = o as IDisposable;
        disposable.Dispose();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It's not uncommon for Dispose to throw exceptions ("already disposed"), so you'd want each dispose call wrapped in a try/catch.

Comment: Dispose shoud *never* throw because of multiple calls. If it does, the component in question doesn't comply with the IDisposable contract. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose.aspx under Remarks: "The object must not throw an exception if its Dispose method is called multiple times."