# Recognize Disposable Objects in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, intellisense, idisposable

It is suggested that `IDisposable` objects should be disposed in either `using` statement or by calling `Dispose()` method. I find it is not intuitive to find out if an object is disposable in Visual Studio.

My question is: is there any way to recognize `IDisposable` objects in VS?

Comment: Why not simply check the classes you use for the `IDisposable` interface and use a `using` statement to instanciate those?

Comment: the intellisense will tell you if it has a dispose method implemented

Comment: I find it is not intuitive to see the implemented interfaces in VS compared to Java IDE. May be Im new to VS!!

Comment: @chris-crush-code While correct in most cases, there's no reason you can't put a `Dispose()` method on an object you create without implementing `IDisposable`.

Comment: Right click on the object in question, select Go To Definition, there you can see how it's implemented. (you might have to go up the stack multiple times)

Comment: @mxmissile Note I have [already answered this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43636775/4631427).

Comment: For what it's worth, there are some things that implement `IDisposable` that you probably don't need to worry about disposing. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/03/25/do-i-need-to-dispose-of-tasks/

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you want to highlight disposable objects differently in VS please check out this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189024/how-can-i-make-all-of-the-idisposable-classes-colored-differently-in-the-visual). I personally prefer Resharper [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28786445/2061604) as I always use R#.

If you just want to figure out if your object is an instance of some interface you can right-button-click on the variable name and `Navigate -> Object Browser` or `Go to Declaration` and then right-button-click on class name `Go to Definition`/`Peek Definition`.

[image]

You might like `Peek Definition` as it shows everything you need inline:

[image]

You can always check what methods object has, if it has `Dispose()` method then 99.9% it's a disposable object. I'll give this 0.01% for those who give methods bad names :).

Comment: Don´t forget the types in you 0.01 % that implement `IDisposable` explicitly. But mostly these types provide a `Close()` method.

Answer (score 24):

I'm surprised that no-one else has mentioned this yet. If your [edition of Visual Studio](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/compare/) supports it, I'd suggest turning on [Code Analysis](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3z0aeatx.aspx) for Build.

Once that's done, pick whatever rule sets you like so long as they ensure that, at the least, [CA2000](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182289.aspx) (Dispose objects before losing scope), [CA2213](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182328.aspx) (Disposable fields should be disposed) and [CA2202](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182334.aspx) (Do not dispose objects multiple times) rules are covered. That way, the compiler should *shout* at you if you're not dealing with disposable objects correctly.

(Although note that getting the compiler to *not* flag some usage of disposable objects can then turn into the bigger challenge, as many StackOverflow questions can attest)

Comment: Can you edit in what these rules are? I have no idea what `CA2213` is and I shouldn't have to go to an external link to find out.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder - I've edited in the rule names. I don't see much value in putting anything further in. I'm linking to the full documentation and even if the links do go bad I'm giving the Code Analysis codes which should remain stable.

Comment: TIPS: You may need to install the MIcrosoft Code Analysis plugin into Visual Studio or the Nuget package into your project.  You will probably want to go Project > References > Analysers > Open Active Rule Set > (Make Changes) > Save As > (file in solution folder).  You then need to update the csproj to use the newly saved rule set.  You may need VS Enterprise also?

Answer (score 8):

You can use Object Browser to view class inheritance hierarchy with implemented interfaces

[image]

Answer (score 6):

For the sake of completeness, if you don't ask how to check it in your code but you just want to know where you can look if the type implements an interface like `IDisposable`, you can always look at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt472912(v=vs.110).aspx).

For example [`FileStream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream(v=vs.110).aspx)

- it's already mentioned in the remarks section:

> This type implements the `IDisposable` interface. When you have finished
>   using the type, you should dispose of it either directly or
>   indirectly. To dispose of the type directly, call its Dispose method
>   in a try/catch block. To dispose of it indirectly, use a language
>   construct such as using (in C#) or Using (in Visual Basic). For more
>   information, see the “Using an Object that Implements IDisposable”
>   section in the IDisposable interface topic.

- or search for the [`Dispose` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227422(v=vs.110).aspx). There you can see if this class or any parent class implements `IDispable`. In this case it is inherited from [`Stream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream(v=vs.110).aspx) which implements that interface which is mentioned at the class syntax and in the remarks section.

  ```
  public abstract class Stream : MarshalByRefObject, IDisposable
  ```

---

If you want to know how to find implementations of an interface in **Visual Studio**, here is already a question that answers that:

[How do you find all implementations of an interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620376/how-do-you-find-all-implementations-of-an-interface)

Comment: I can find interfaces easily in Java (less than 1 sec) but I find it is quite hard to see it in C#. Searching for IDisapsable is much slower.

Comment: @TDNguyen How do you do it in Java?

Comment: @TDNguyen. Yes; i'm missing also a list of all interfaces that a type implements either directly or indirectly through parent types. There's only an inheritance hierarchy that doesn't contain the interfaces.

Comment: @DavidG: in the javadocs you see all implenented interfaces directly at the top of a type: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html

Comment: @TDNguyen the easist way is to search on google, just do `msdn YourClassHere` and the first result is almost always the microsoft MSDN page for the class that tells you all the information for it.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: yes, but i'm missing a list of all implemented interfaces of a given type in MSDN. You have to click through all classes in the inheritance hierarchy

Comment: @TimSchmelter true, one easy way to get that list though is to do the "Navigate to Metadata" in Visual Studio it shows the inherited interfaces in that view. It also has the added benifit of working on any types instead of just the framework ones.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yes, but OP implies it's an IDE thing, not a docs thing. Also, docs will only help for framework types, not custom ones.

Comment: I'm now thinking we should dupe this to your linked question.

Answer (score 6):

As a (silly?) alternative to shelling out for Resharper and its ilk, Visual Studio does have the concept of *External Tools* (in the Tools menu), which you could (ab)use to do something like:

- **Title:** `Is Disposa&ble`
- **Command:** `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`
- **Arguments:** `-Command "&{$i=[Type]::GetType('System.IDisposable');[AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()|%{ $_.GetTypes()}|?{$_.FullName.EndsWith('.$(CurText)')}|%{New-Object PSObject -Property @{'Type'=$_;'IDisposable'=$i.IsAssignableFrom($_)}}|ft}"`
- **Use Output window:** *checked*

This would read whatever string you had selected in the editor, search for .NET types with that string as a name and show a True/False as to whether that string implemented IDisposable.

The Powershell command in the tool is just the *quickest* approach I could do to demonstrate the possibility, but it is far from perfect -- it only finds types in assemblies that Powershell loads by default.  If you wanted to expand on the idea, you could build a command-line .NET app that loaded your project and scanned all the assemblies that your project loaded.

If you highlighted the word `Stream` in your code, for example, and ran your external tool (<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>,<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> in the example), it would return:

```
Type             IDisposable
----             -----------
System.IO.Stream        True
```

To break down the Powershell command:

```
&{ $i=[Type]::GetType('System.IDisposable');        # Get the IDisposable interface
   [AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() `     # Get all loaded assemblies
    | %{ $_.GetTypes() } `                          # For each assembly, get all types
    | ?{ $_.FullName.EndsWith('.$(CurText)') } `    # Filter types that are named $(CurText) - $(CurText) is a macro within VS External Tools
    | %{ New-Object PSObject -Property @{           # For each type, return an object containing...
         'Type' = $_;                               # ...the type name...
         'IDisposable' = $i.IsAssignableFrom($_)    # ...and whether the IDisposable interface is implemented
       } } `
    | ft }                                          # Format all returned objects as a table
```

Comment: Like you said this snippet of PowerShell could use a few improvements, but as a proof-of-concept starting point this is great, not silly.  After the initial setup this should be the quickest way to determine if the selected text is a type that implements `IDisposable` _without_ the need for third-party tools or traipsing through the hierarchy manually.  +1!

Answer (score 5):

A way to see what interfaces a class implements, along with all of it's publicly exposed fields, properties, methods etc. is to go to that class in the code. For example:

```
Image image = Image.FromFile(path);
```

Make sure you click on the class, not the instance and press F12. This will take you to a metadata file for that class. For example: the `Image.cs` file has the following above class declaration:

```
public abstract class Image : MarshalByRefObject, ISerializable, ICloneable, IDisposable
```

You can then also use F12 to click through to other classes. Note that these classes are usually shown up in the Light Blue colour in Visual Studio:

[image: Screenshot showing light blue colours.]

You can also get to this meta data file by right clicking on the class and selecting "Go To Definition" from the drop down list.

---

Though not ideal you can also go to an instance of the class and put a `.` on the end. This should bring up the intellisense and you will be able to see `Dispsose()` in the list if the item implements the interface.

You could also just write `myInstance.Dispose();` or `using (myInstance = new MyClass()) {}` and if it compiles the class implements the interface else it doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way to find out this is by using memory warning in Code Analysis.

1. Enable Code Analysis to "Run on build" on project properties.
   [image]
2. Look for following warnings after build

**[CA2000](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca2000?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(CA2000)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%2CVersion%253Dv4.8)%26rd%3Dtrue)**

A local object of an IDisposable type is created, but the object is not disposed before all references to the object are out of scope.

**[CA2213](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2015/code-quality/ca2213-disposable-fields-should-be-disposed?view=vs-2015&redirectedfrom=MSDN)**

A type that implements System.IDisposable declares fields that are of types that also implement IDisposable. The Dispose method of the field is not called by the Dispose method of the declaring type.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case "Code Analysis" was not showing the `CS2000` rule when I build the project or ran "Analyze - Run Code Analysis".

There's an `.editorconfig` file in the solution root, where you can add this line:

```
dotnet_diagnostic.CA2000.severity = warning
```

After that code analysis started showing rule violations.

Alternative solution was to add this line to the project file:

```
 <AnalysisMode>All</AnalysisMode>
```

But this slows the build down severely. So enable/disable as needed, ad-hoc.

It appears that the default analysis level rule-set is lower, than required to detect this particular rule-violation.

Answer (score -2):

`either using or in Dispose() method` Use the `using` construct when you can.  Here's why.  Using this MSDN example, here are two equivalent blocks of code.  This one with `using`:

```
using (Font font1 = new Font("Arial", 10.0f)) 
{
    byte charset = font1.GdiCharSet;
}
```

This one without `using`:

```
{
    Font font1 = new Font("Arial", 10.0f);
    try
    {
        byte charset = font1.GdiCharSet;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (font1 != null)
            ((IDisposable)font1).Dispose();
    }
}
```

Each part of the second block is there for a reason: the curly braces, the try-finally, the null check, and the cast to IDisposable.  No one should be expected to remember this.  That's why the `using` construct exists.

Comment: I think the question is not _why_ one should use `using`/`Dispose()`, but rather how to recognize which objects implement `IDisposable` and, therefore, should be handled by using `using`/`Dispose()`.  In other words, you say "Use the `using` construct when you can" and the question is asking "In Visual Studio, how do I know 'when I can'?"

Answer (score -3):

Something clean that can be done in C#7

```
class Foo : IDisposable {
    string _bar = "init";
    void Fooy() { _bar = "fooy"; }

    public void Dispose() {
        _bar = null;       
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        var v = new Foo();
        Console.WriteLine(v._bar);
        if(v is IDisposable id) using(id)
            v.Fooy();
        else
            v.Fooy();

        Console.WriteLine(v._bar ?? "null");;

    }
}
```

`Fooy` could be some *virtual* or *abstract* function. Some base classes may implement `IDisposable` while others not. Try running the above code. The console will print different text depending whether or not `IDisposable` has been implemented

Comment: v.Fooy() else v.Fooy()? Is that a typo?

Comment: @EdPlunkett I think calling the same method on both sides of the `if` is "correct" (though I don't agree that it's "clean").  The idea is to call `v.Fooy()` whether or not `v` implements `IDisposable`, then dispose of `v` (via `using`) if it does implement `IDisposable`.  Perhaps translating `using` to `try`/`finally` would make it clearer: `try { v.Fooy(); } finally { if (v is IDisposable id) id.Dispose(); }`, but it still seems like a runtime solution to an IDE/documentation issue.

Comment: Your right BACON. That would be the way to go about doing it. I was just playing around with some CS7 code.

Comment: @BACON Ahhh, now I see. The purpose is just to get `using(id)` in there. Thank you.