# How to show (identify easily) `Disposable` variables within Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, resharper, dispose, idisposable, disposable

*[I have searched similar questions, but most of them seem at least 5 years old. The most near seemed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28786445/2377343) but it is not clear answer and is 5yrs old]*

My question: What should we do if we want Visual Studio showed (I)Disposable variables and properties with different color (or somehow visually noticeable) in IDE? For example, I easily spoted all such cases in VisualStudio:

```
var x = new XYZ();  //XYZ has .dispose() method
// or
var x = otherType.ToXYZ();
// or
var x = anotherVariableFromOtherClass;  //so this `anotherVariable` has also dispose()
```

I have tried Resharper (but couldn't achieve using the above referred answer). I am also ok with free/simple approaches outside of Resharper too.

Comment: How I can't bear contr-questions `why do you need that`... :/ I am searching for solution for question. reason doesn't matter.

Comment: as per the question you referred it is not possible currently unless it is in built within language services by MS